# Go Web Assembly cannot Click Run when enter http://localhost:8080/wasm_exec.html

Tags: go, webassembly

I am new to stackoverflow and golang web assembly

I am struggled with the Question: I write a test code

```
main.go

package main

func main(){
    println("hello world")
}
```

And I have generated main.wasm and imported wasm_exec.js and wasm_exec.html to the working dir

I also write a webserver

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

var (
    listen = flag.String("listen", ":8080", "listen address")
    dir    = flag.String("dir", ".", "directory to serve")
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    log.Printf("listening on %q...", *listen)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(*listen, http.FileServer(http.Dir(*dir)))
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
```

I use Chrome and enter http://localhost:8080/wasm_exec.html

According to the materials online, there is a "Run" button which is available to click.

However, actually I cannot click this button

I am really confused about that

This is my first question on stackoverflow .

Sorry for the bad English

Comment: Check your HTML code. Probably your HTML code for adding "Run" button is disabled by default and you are not enabling it from your Go code. eg. <button type="button" disabled>Run</button> .You can also remove the disabled keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step by step `Hello World` from Go WebAssembly:
`web/main.go` file:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(".")))
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

`main.go` file:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World")
}
```

Run the following commands in Linux terminal (for Windows OS replace `cp` with `copy` and `$GOROOT` with `%GOROOT%`):

```sh
GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build -o test.wasm
cp $GOROOT/misc/wasm/wasm_exec.html ./
cp $GOROOT/misc/wasm/wasm_exec.js ./

go run web/main.go
```

Open `http://127.0.0.1:8080/wasm_exec.html`

Now in the Browser Right click inside Browser then select `Inspect` then select `Console` tab, and now it is time to click on the `Run` button, then you will see the `Hello World` inside the Browser Console.

Comment: I have another problem when I see your codes on github(wasmup/go109calc). I want to see how it works so I copy your codes in my Goland. But when i run it, the Browser Console detects error-------Uncaught (in promise) LinkError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #18 module="go" function="syscall/js.copyBytesToJS" error: function import requires a callable

Comment: And when I click the Factorial and isPrime it also detects errors Uncaught ReferenceError: isPrime is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):32)

Comment: But it acutally works on your github html. So I don't know why . My OS is windows 10  Thanks in advance

Comment: You should not run WebAssembly Codes this way, like this answer, first run in terminal: `cd goserve && go install && cd ..` then run `goserve` which is equal to above `go run web/main.go` then you are good to go and Open `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`

Comment: I don't know how to use Markdown so sorry about that .I make index.html main.go main.js main.css test.wasm(generated by main.go)  wasm_exec.js web.go(which is you said the web/main.go)  on the same directory  Then I run web.go And then I open localhost:8080

Comment: And there is a weird phenomenon When I go to the page The Console automatically output a number 1575726005118n

Comment: is it a link problem? between go and js ?

Comment: or it doesn't launch test.wasm at all

Comment: sorry for my impoliteness because it's really urgent

Comment: the error says about "syscall/js" but i have make the env correct GOOS =js and GOARCH = wasm

Comment: Start with simple example e.g. `go104factorial`

Comment: `cd go104factorial` then `GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build -o static/js/main.wasm` then `go run ../goserve/` then Open `http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/` that is all.

Comment: thank you sincerely And one more question whether it still works  if I move the functions you write in main.js into main.go

Comment: It is Ok to move all functions from main.js to main.go, only you need to keep `WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(...)` inside main.js. that is all.